# Does redux-form field value can hold object instead of just a string?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Does redux-form field value can hold object instead of just a string?

Consider following example

```
    class SelectQuestions extends Component{
          render(){
    const {fields:{question1,question2},handleSubmit}=this.props;
    return <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSumbit(this.handleFunction.bind(this))}>
        <SelectQuestion {...question1}/>
        <SelectQuestion {...question1}/>
       <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    }
    }
class SelectQuestion extends Component{

render (){

 <select></select> 
}    

}
```

'SelectQuestion' takes array of Questions, each Question has question id and question name.

Once the user selects the question I wanted to to return QuesionId and QuesitonName. How it can be achieved using redux-form in react

Answer (score 7):

**TL:DR**

Yes it can hold an object. Check out this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vq6k6195rl

**Explanation:**

For a select, you can define your selects like this:

```
const myFancyQuestions = [
  { id: 1, label: 'Why?', category: 'Asking why' },
  { id: 2, label: 'Who?', category: 'Asking who' },
  { id: 3, label: 'When?', category: 'Asking when' }
];
```

Then wrap your component with Field component.

```
<Field component={ObjectSelect} name="myFancySelect" options={myFancyQuestions}/>
```

And then just show it in your render:

```
class ObjectSelect extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { input, multiple, options, value, ...rest } = this.props;
    const parse = event => {
      // This is what redux-form will hold:
      return JSON.parse(event.target.value);
    }
    return (
      <select
        onBlur={event => input.onBlur(parse(event))}
        onChange={event => input.onChange(parse(event))}
        {...rest}>
          {options.map(option =>
            <option key={option.id} 
                    value={JSON.stringify(option)} 
                    selected={input.value.id == option.id}>
              {option.label}
            </option>)}
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the value can be a complex object. There's even an example demonstrating it.

[Complex Values Example](http://redux-form.com/5.2.3/#/examples/complex)

Comment: How does this apply to redux-form v7? The Complex Values Example page is not part of the docs anymore.

Comment: Yes, v7 can still hold an object.

Comment: Neat, but how? Passing an object to the Field doesn't seem to work and as mentioned in my previous comment, the Complex Values docs page doesn't exist anymore. Do you plan to add it back at a later time? In the meantime we could just JSON.stringify() the object but if there is a cleaner way, I'm all for it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to achieve that is to create two virtual fields `selectedQuestionId` and `selectedQuestionName`. Those fields are not to display. Then, each `SelectQuestion` can trigger a callback like:

```
setSelectedQuestion = (event) => {
  var questionName = event.target.name; //or something like that
  var questionId = event.target.id; //or something like that
  this.props.fields.selectedQuestionName.onChange(questionName );
  this.props.fields.selectedQuestionId.onChange(questionId );
}
```

`onChange` can be called on redux-form fields to programmatically set the value.

Comment: Does this mean redux field cannot hold an object? Instead only a string value

Comment: From what [redux-form reducer does](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/reducer.js#L64) with the value, I guess it could be an object: there is no uses of this value inside reduc-form framework that will force you to use a string. So you should be able to call onChange with an object as parameter

Comment: Yes, it can still hold an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but still..

Yes, it can! You can simply use a [FormSection](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formsection.md/) here.

It will split your form to an objects under the hood, and will keep all sections separtely in your single form object.

Just need to pass a `name` prop to the FormSection, that will be a name of your sub-object.

```
import { FormSection } from 'redux-form';

render(){
  return(
      <form onSubmit={...}>
        <FormSection name="firstGroup">
            <SelectQuestion {...question1}/>
        </FormSection>

        <FormSection name="secondGroup">
            <SelectQuestion {...question1}/>
        </FormSection>
       <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
  )
}
```

Then check your form structure through the Redux devTools.

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you can just add ".value" (or anything else..) to name prop and it will create object and update value inside it on changes...

```
<Field name="companyName.value"  placeholder="Name of the Company" component={ReduxFormTextInput} />
```

And you will get object :

```
companyName: {
value:"<inputted string>"
}
```