# redux-form: Change specific field value on click

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

How can I change value of specific field on event.

**Example** not working (Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined)

```
onclick1() {
  this.props.fields.firstname.onChange("John")
}
render() {
 const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
 return (
  <div>
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}>

      <Field
        name="firstname"
        component={TextField}
        label="first name"
      />
      <button onClick="this.onclick1()">Set name to John</button>

      <button type="submit">
        okay
      </button>
   </form>
```

This solution was proposed here but it is not working for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36916183/160059

redux-form v7

Comment: How does your form look like? Will you share some code?

Comment: @Dario Updated example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some problems in your code:

```
<button onClick="this.onclick1()">
```

should be:

```
<button onClick={this.onclick1}>
```

and onclick1 should be somehow bound to the component. Besides, I usually use `change` method to set a field value. So I would change your code to something like:

```
class ComplexForm extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onclick1 = this.onclick1.bind(this);
  }

  onclick1() {
    this.props.change("firstname", "John");
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field name="firstname" component="input" label="first name" />
        <button onClick={this.onclick1}>Set name to John</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I only rewrote some relevant part of your code and I'm using a standard `input` component cause I don't know how your `TextField` looks like. Check online demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w9vn3zmmr)