# Handling objects in component that expects Text

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm not sure how to explain my problem, but my API sends the information in objects:

```
"brand": {
    "id": 48,
    "name": "Nike"
  },
```

And i need to edit this brand, when i pass this brands on Initial values:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  const quality = state.quality;
  const edition = state.editionBox;
  const levels = state.levels;
  const tenant = state.tenant;
  const productID = props.match.params.id;
  if (productID) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    return { initialValues: state.products.productList.find(product => product.id == productID), levels, quality, edition, tenant}
  } else {
    return { brands: state.brands, levels, quality, edition, tenant }
  }
}
```

My component, expect to just a brandName, not id and name

```
<Field
 name="brand"
                      label="Marca"
                      component={RenderedSelect}
                      validate={[required]}>
                      {brandsList.map(brand => (
                        <MenuItem key={brand.id} value={brand.name}>
                          {brand.name}
                        </MenuItem>
                      ))}
                    </Field>
```

This is my redux when i select a brand, i need to get the ID and Name

[image]

EDIT: i got this error no console:

[image]

EDIT2: My brandList coming from useSelector from redux-state

```
const brandsList = useSelector(state => state.brands.brandList);
```

Comment: Where are you getting brandsList from inside the component? Is it coming from redux state as a prop?

Comment: @Hyetigran tks for answer! i got this using useSelector.

Comment: Gotcha! It seems you want to access id and name properties for each brand in the Menu Item but are not able to. Is that right?

Comment: @Hyetigran 
Yes, FieldArray through the Redux-form documentation does this. But I wanted that at the time of Submit, the values ​​would send the ID and Name, not just the Name. I believe that these 2 problems are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Erik R., the creator of redux-form answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36960052/4312466), you can stringify the Select's options values, using `JSON.stringify`:

```
<Field
  name="brand"
  label="Marca"
  component={RenderedSelect}
  validate={[required]}>
  { brandsList.map(brand => (
    <MenuItem key={brand.id} value={JSON.stringify(brand)}>
      {brand.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Field>
```

Some important notes:

1. Now, submitting the form, you will have the brand object stringified and you may need converting it back to an object using `JSON.parse`.
2. In order to set brand `initialValues` correctly, please make sure to stringify it firstly. Otherwise, passing an object literal, won't set the initial value of brand Select.
3. You can abstract and reuse the above two steps, i.e. stringifying/parsing, in your `RenderSelect` component. In a similar way, Erik R. implemented it in his [`ObjectSelect.js` example](https://redux-form.com/5.2.3/#/examples/complex?_k=66jyfj).

Comment: I didn't quite understand. What is the change I should make to InitialValues ​​when I have a string that looks like this? `initialValues: state.products.productList.find(product => product.id == productID`

Comment: Looking at your use-case, you may not change your `initialValues`. But if you want to set an initial value to a specific brand, you should set it as follow: `initialValues: { brand: JSON.stringify({ id: 48, name: "Nike"  }) }`.

Comment: Ok, work using this on initialValues, i need to this for all fields? `return { initialValues: {
      id: obj.id,
      name: obj.name,
      brand: JSON.stringify(obj.brand),
    }}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I have several fields in my state, so I'm using initialValues ​​to pass those fields from the state. Do I have to go through this way that I am going through or is there another way?

`const obj = state.products.productList.find(product => product.id == productID);
    if (obj){
      return { initialValues: {
        id: obj.id,
        sku: obj.sku,
        name: obj.name,
        brand: JSON.stringify(obj.brand),
        category: JSON.stringify(obj.category),
        quality: obj.quality,
        subCategory: JSON.stringify(obj.subCategory),
        level: obj.level}}`

Comment: And the same question when submitting, I have to do it for each field or I can do the command for everyone. Ex:

`onEditProduct (JSON.parse (values));`

Comment: It's fine the way you do it. About stringifying/parsing - just do it only for the needed field, i.e. for the object fields. As I mentioned, you can abstract stringifying/parsing this object in your custom Select component, as in the example link I shared. BTW I'm handling the object fields in the same way with stringifying/parsing.

Comment: @LuizHenrique did you manage to handle the object via redux-form? If so, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Ye, it's working, i'm sorry. Thanks for the answer!